# Global JavaScript Variable Scope: Why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, scope

So I'm playing around with JavaScript and came across what I think to be an oddity. Is anyone able to explain the following? (i've included the alerted values as comments)

Why is the first alert(msg) inside foo() returning *undefined* and not *outside*?

```
var msg = 'outside';

function foo() {
  alert(msg); // undefined

  var msg = 'inside';
  alert(msg); // inside
}

foo();    
alert(msg); // outside
```

Considering these both work fine:

```
var msg = 'outside';

function foo() {
  alert(msg); // outside
}

alert(msg); // outside
```

and:

```
var msg = 'outside';

function foo() {
  var msg = 'inside';
  alert(msg); // inside
}

alert(msg); // outside
```

Comment: Can you show the full context of the 1st script?

Comment: I forgot to add the call to foo(); but other than that, this is the full context of it. I was just playing around with variable scopes and came across this.

Comment: never mind, it's already solved, I was suspecting something else.

Comment: You cannot have at the same scope level, two variables with the same name..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What is happening in your first example is the declaration and initlization of msg are being split with the declaration being hoisted to the top of the closure.

```
var msg; //declaration
msg = "inside" //initialization
```

Therefore the code you wrote is the same thing as

```
var msg = 'outside';

function foo() {
var msg;  
alert(msg); // undefined
msg = 'inside';
alert(msg); // inside
}
```

The second example is not the same. In your second example you have not declared a local variable msg so alert(msg) refers to the global msg.
Here is some further reading on:
[Hoisting](http://bustingseams.blogspot.com/2009/08/another-javascript-pitfall-hoisting.html)

Comment: Any other information as to why this is interpreted that way, considering the second example works without issue? It seems the same to me, only it has code following it...

Comment: I wasn't quite sure why I got the downvote either. Either way, like the other answers that are appearing here, the reason is variable declarations in javascript are hoisted. This means that they are moved to the top of the closure.

Comment: @Cory the second example has no `var msg` in it. The `var` makes it a local variable, and the twist is it makes it so even *before* the physical location of the `var`.

Comment: @Shaun ah, gotcha! Thanks for the insight! Didn't know var's where hoisted. GREAT to know.

Comment: @Shaun by the time i've read your post the "var msg;" wasn't there and so i looked like nonsense to me.

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it quite a bit more cleaner. It is just a bit more complex as a result.

Comment: @Pekka gotcha. I just changed var msg = 'inside'; to msg = 'inside'; and it works like i thought it would in the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Variable declarations inside a Javascript closure take place first, regardless of where they are located within the the closure. So in your first example, a **local** variables `msg` exists at the start of the function (because it is declared within the function) but a value is not assigned to it until after the first `alert`, so for that first alert, `msg` is undefined.

Your first example is equivalent to:

```
var msg = 'outside';

function foo() {
  var msg;
  alert(msg); // undefined

  msg = 'inside';
  alert(msg); // inside
}

alert(msg); // outside
```

In the second example, you don't explicitly declare `msg` within the function. Since there is already a global variable with the same name, the global is used instead of a local being defined.

In the third example, you explicitly declare the variable and assign it a value before trying to use it, so when you `alert(msg)`, the local, defined variable is alerted.

Answer (score 2):

from http://www.irt.org/script/1321.htm:

> If we declare but not initalise a variable with the `var` keyword inside a function it should be local in scope, but `undefined` across the complete function until the point at which it is [initialized]...

this will work for you:

```
var msg = 'outside';

function foo() {
  alert(window.msg); // outside

  var msg = 'inside';
  alert(msg); // inside
}

alert(msg); // outside
foo();
alert(msg); // still "outside"
```

Answer (score 1):

`var` is not a declaration. It is a confusion that mixes up many people. Rather, `var` is a *scope-wide* annotation. **The placement of 'var' inside a scope does not matter.**

[var in JavaScript is an Annotation, not Statement](http://izra.org/posts/2010/01/19/js-var-is-an-annotation/)

Answer (score 1):

You can completely **control the execution** of **java script functions** and pass variables as a argument,

Here in this **case** function inside you **can not access outside variable**. but if you want to use you **pass variable argument** to access that value inside function.

```
var msg = 'outside';

function foo(msg) {
  alert(msg); // outside

  var msg = 'inside';
  alert(msg); // inside
}

foo(msg);    
alert(msg); // outside
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ar8K9/5/)**</kbd>

And **inside another variable** g you define is a 'private' variables (with in a **function scope**) so its alert "inside" value within function. Hope this help you!