# JavaScript scope oddity

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why the global x reverted to 1 after the scopeTest function exits. Can somebody explain this to me? If I comment out the definition of x within the local scope of the function, x will change and point to 200. Otherwise, it remains 1... !!!

```
//setting global variable x to 1
var x = 1;

function scopeTest() {
    x = 200; //setting global x to 200
    alert(x); //200

    var x = 500; //creating a local variable x and setting it to 500
    alert(x); //500
}
scopeTest();
alert(x); //why is x 1 instead of 200?
```

Comment: and [Strange javascript scoping issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17662458/218196)

Comment: and [global scope and local scope in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20602377/218196)

Comment: and [Global JavaScript Variable Scope: Why doesn't this work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2685388/218196)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

welcome to **variable Hoisting** trap:
in javasript, variable declarations are moved to the beginning of the outer(containing) function, so your code is actually equivalent to:

```
function scopeTest() {
    var x;
    x = 200; //setting local x to 200
    alert(x); //200

    x = 500; //creating a local variable x and setting it to 500
    alert(x); //500
}
```