# Scope chain - javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript, and while learning I got confused. Not sure about title of the question.

Coming straight to point -

```
var a = 4,
    say = console.log,
    globalA; // defined global variable's


doSome();
doSomeMore();

function doSome() {
    say(a);
    var a = 5;
    say(++a);
}

function doSomeMore() {
    say(a);
}
```

When I run it, this gives

> undefined
>
> 6
>
> 4

Why is this when `doSome` executes it has value of `a` as `undefined` and not `4` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global JavaScript Variable Scope: Why doesn't this work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685388/global-javascript-variable-scope-why-doesnt-this-work)

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842244/javascript-odd-scoping-behavior, http://stackoverflow.com/q/20602377/218196, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842244/javascript-odd-scoping-behavior

Comment: @FelixKling I believe the more of these threads we have the better (pointing towards the same resources of course, which makes what you did worth a lot), if not just simply due to the undescriptive nature of the problem. If people knew to google "why do variables get hoisted" there'd be no need to ask.

Comment: @FelixKling - True. Please mark as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

It essentially means that when you declare `var a` in a function this gets moved to the top, and is equal to the following:

```
function doSome() {
    var a; //initialize the variable using hoisting
    say(a); //undefined
    a = 5;
    say(++a);
}
```

If you remove `var` in `var a = 5` this works as you'd want it to as it then refers to the global `a` variable:

```
function doSome() {
    say(a); //4
    a = 5;
    say(++a);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this makes real sense. Even when I was using `window.a` I was getting my value. Thanks :) Accepting (in 3 min) & Up-voted (esp. for the link)

Answer (score 0):

change your code

```
function doSome() {
    say(a);
    var a = 5;
    say(++a);
}
```

to

function doSome() {

```
var a = 5;
say(a);
say(++a);
```

}