# JavaScript unexpected variable scope behavior

Tags: javascript, global-variables, scope

I would to know something about a scope behavior.

For example I have a variable and a function:

```
var test = 1;
function scope(){
    alert(test);
    test=2;
}
scope();
alert(test);
```

This will display 1 and 2. No problem. But if I do this:

```
var test = 1;
function scope(){
    alert(test);
    var test = 2;
}
scope();
alert(test);
```

This will display 'undefined' and '1'. Why does the variable come out as 'undefined'?

Comment: Because test as defined inside the scope has still not been assigned a value.

Comment: please read about **hoisting.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global JavaScript Variable Scope: Why doesn't this work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685388/global-javascript-variable-scope-why-doesnt-this-work)

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/q/20602377/218196, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842244/javascript-odd-scoping-behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you havn't created any local variable but accessed the `test` defined from the global scope.

```
var test = 1;        // Global Test - GT

function scope() {
    alert(test);     // Accesses GT
    test = 2;        // Assigns to GT
}
scope();
alert(test);         // Accesses GT
```

But in the second case, you are creating a new variable, but accessing it before assigning a value it. By default, all the unassigned variables will have `undefined`.

In JavaScript, variables are scoped to the functions in which they are declared. So, when you use `var variable_name` in a function, you are creating new variable and it will be accessible to all parts of the function. Also, you are creating a variable with the same name as the global variable. When JavaScript looks up for the variable `test`, it will first search the local scope of the function and it will be found there. So, local `test` variable will be used.

```
alert(test);     // value will be `undefined` till a value is assigned.
var test = 2;    // Declared a new variable and assigned value here
```

This behavior is called [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope).

Comment: But in both cases, I assigned a value before my function.

Comment: @geopl no - in the second case you assign the value after the alert. That's why you get `undefined`.

Comment: @geopl Please check the answer now, I have added few more explanation

Comment: Ok ok. I understood that we have an undefined value if the variable is assigned later but what I found weird is that in the second case, it doesn't get my global variable.

Comment: @geopl In JavaScript, variables are scoped to the functions in which they are declared. So, when you use var variable_name in a function, you are creating new variable and it will be accessible to all parts of the function. Also, you are creating a variable with the same name as the global variable. When JavaScript looks up for the variable test, it will first search the local scope of the function and it will be found there. So, local test variable will be used.

Comment: Ok if I understood: In the second case, it will search the local scope and find that my variable is assigned after but it can't access to my value. So it will not search outside of my function.

Comment: To access my global variable I have to specify that I want to get it from the window object so I can do this : window.test and then it works. (IMPORTANT: It doesn't work in Jsfiddle beause it seems to block it.)

Answer (score 2):

Hoisting :

your second code :

```
var test = 1;
function scope(){
    alert(test);
    var test = 2;
}
scope();
alert(test);
```

is actually :

```
var test = 1;
function scope(){
    var test;
    alert(test);
    test = 2;
}
scope();
alert(test);
```

same catch here :

```
var test = 1;
function scope(){
    if (typeof test =="undefined") alert(2)

    var test = 2;
}
scope();
alert(test);
```